# uploading an image: requested URL was not found on the server

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, flask

I am very new to flask, and I'm trying to create a simple image uploader app.

I've checked my code against other guides on how to create these kinds of apps, and my code looks to be alright, but when I try to actually submit an image, it says that "The requested URL was not found on the server". I think I might have an error in my js since the console doesn't log "success", but I'm not sure how to fix that. Any help would be really appreciated and needed.

My js and html codes:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("submission").click(function() {
        var form_data = new FormData($('#submit_file')[0]);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/submit_image',
            data: form_data,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("success");
            }

        })
    })
})
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>Image Upload</h1>
    <form action="/submit_image" id = "submit_file">
        <input type="file" id="image_file" name="image_to_be_uploaded">
        <input type="submit" id="submission">
    </form>
</body>
```

And this is my python/flask code:

```js
@app.route('/submit_image', methods=['POST'])
def submit_image():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file_val = request.files['file']
        #if file_val.filename != '':
        file_val.save(file_val.filename)
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

@app.errorhandler(413)
def too_large(e):
    return "File is too large", 413
```

Comment: display the url not found

Comment: @Frenchy do you mean this? http://127.0.0.1:5000/submit_image?image_to_be_uploaded=368757_600.jpg

Comment: it says 404 not found (The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.)

Comment: so the server doesnt found the file..where have you put the image ? the folder?

Comment: @Frenchy The image is on my desktop. Theoretically, I should be able to pull any image from my computer and submit/upload it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript code will never be executed. The form is transmitted in its standard behavior.
Since you have not specified an attribute method, the form is transmitted with the GET method.

```
<form 
  name="submit_image" 
  action="{{ url_for('submit_image') }}" 
  method="post" 
  enctype="multipart/form-data"
>
  <input type="file" name="image" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The transmitted form data is queried based on its name.

```
@app.route('/submit_image', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def submit_image():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file_val = request.files['image']
        # if file_val.filename != '':
        #   Handle empty filename here!
        file_val.save(file_val.filename)
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    
    return render_template('submit_image.html')
```

Now it should work without javascript.

If you want to send the image via your Javascript code and use a submit button, I recommend using the submit event of the form as well. The `preventDefault` function suppresses the standard behavior of the form.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form[name='submit_image']").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    $.ajax({
      type: $(this).attr("method"),
      url: $(this).attr("action"),
      data: formData,
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log("success");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

It should work now.

---

The following code is an example of how you can save the files within a folder and serve them again. You will need to create a new folder. "<APP_ROOT>/var/app-instance/images"

```
import os
from flask import (
    current_app,
    redirect, 
    render_template, 
    request, 
    send_from_directory
)
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

def allowed_file(filename):
    allowed_extensions = current_app.config.get(
        'ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS',
        { 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif' }
    )
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in allowed_extensions

@app.route('/submit_image', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def submit_image():
    dest_folder = current_app.config.get('UPLOAD_FOLDER', 'images')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'image' not in request.files:
            return redirect(request.url)

        file_val = request.files['image']

        if file_val.filename == '':
            return redirect(request.url)
        
        if file_val and allowed_file(file_val.filename):
            dest = os.path.join(
                current_app.instance_path,
                dest_folder,
                secure_filename(file_val.filename))
            file_val.save(dest)

    images = os.listdir(os.path.join(
        current_app.instance_path,
        dest_folder))

    return render_template('submit_image.html', images=images)

@app.route('/serve_image/<path:filename>')
def serve_image(filename):
    dest_folder = current_app.config.get('UPLOAD_FOLDER', 'images')
    return send_from_directory(
        os.path.join(current_app.instance_path, dest_folder),
        filename
    )
```

```
<h1>Image Upload</h1>
<form
  name="submit_image"
  action="{{ url_for('submit_image') }}"
  method="post"
  enctype="multipart/form-data"
>
  <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

<table>
  {% for img in images -%}
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img
        src="{{ url_for('serve_image', filename=img) }}"
        style="width: 84px; height: auto;" />
      </td>
    <td>
      <a
        href="{{ url_for('serve_image', filename=img) }}"
        target="_blank"
      >{{ img }}</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor -%}
</table>
```

Comment: @norwegian_forest Check the attribute "name" of the input field. If it does not match the query in ```request.files```, a type of ```KeyError``` is thrown which leads to this error message. The key-value pair queried is not part of the form data.

Comment: @norwegian_forest When the submission is finished a file should be written.
Which parts of my code did you use? Is an error thrown inside the console?

Comment: I used all parts of your code. The only messages I have in the console are "POST /submit_image HTTP/1.1" 302 - and "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - . In the part you commented out, I did do if file_val.filename == '': return "Invalid image", 400 , but the result is the same whether I comment that part out or not

Comment: The javascript code is not executed again. But a file should be written. Due to the redirect, you will be forwarded using the status code 302 FOUND. Please compare the code again and look in the directory from which you started the application for the image. From a distance it is difficult to detect the fault.

Comment: @norwegian_forest In which folder do they appear? You should list the files in the directory. A folder called "static" from which you can load files with the help of ```url_for('static', filename = <your_filename>)``` has a special meaning in this context. Otherwise you will need a new route and have to serve the files yourself using ```send_from_directory(<directory>, <filename>)```.

Comment: —the images appear in my general folder that also contains "static", "pycache", "app.py", and "templates" folders. the static folder contains the css and js folders and respective files. Do you mean substitute url_for('index') with the url_for('static', filename=file_var.filename)?

Comment: @norwegian_forest I edited my answer and wrote you a possible variant without using javascript.

Comment: @norwegian_forest I would be happy if your question was answered to your satisfaction and helpful approaches were included. If there is still a need for explanation, please let me know.

Comment: —oh, I'd been working on other stuff for a while and didn't see your updates—thank you! I've tried them, but somehow the new folder I created inside my parent folder doesn't have the images put into it, so I was wondering if I should do something like current_app.config.get('UPLOAD_FOLDER', <current folder>)? OR should I use 'SECRET_KEY' app config?

Comment: @norwegian_forest The instance_path is by default a directory with the path "/var/app-instance". With the line you mentioned, a subfolder is referenced. If the information is not available in the configuration, the second value is used. If the folder does not exist you should be able to see the full path that is requested in the console within an error message. My entry "<APP_ROOT>" only refers to the project folder.

Comment: my root folder name is imageUploader, and it seems like my directory is ...imageUploader/instance/images/<image file name>. So I'm missing that /var/app-instance part. Is there a 'special' way to create the "images" folder (I'm on mac os and just created a new folder within imageUploader)?

Comment: @norwegian_forest Nope, I'm on mac os too. Just create the folder.

Comment: @norwegian_forest This platform lives from the fact that there are volunteers who are willing to sacrifice their time and use their knowledge to help others to solve their problems. In order to give these people feedback on the success of their measures, the users are given a wide variety of means. It would be nice if the questioner would use this to rate the answer and / or mark the question as answered. Even if you have received an answer, it is always possible to clarify any resulting ambiguities with comments. I hope that you understand my concerns and thank you for your attention.